# how to get an uri of an image resource in android

Tags: android, uri

I need to open an intent to view an image as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("@drawable/sample_1.jpg");
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is that `Uri uri = Uri.parse("@drawable/sample_1.jpg");` is incorrect.

Answer (score 153):

The format is:

`"android.resource://[package]/[res id]"`

[package] is your package name

[res id] is **value of** the resource ID, e.g. R.drawable.sample_1

to stitch it together, use

`Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/" + R.drawable.sample_1);`

Comment: Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://net.londatiga.android.twitpic/" + R.drawable.icon); String mpath = path.toString();  I get No such file or directory error when i am doing this

Comment: when i try to send image as email attachment it is sending the file but without .jpg extension. So the image isn't valid in the receipients pc.

Comment: @hemanthkumar See this answer as a reference : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8476930/62921 He explain that there is no  drawable folder except on your machine. That's why it uses IDs and that your path.toString() doesn't work.

Comment: This does not work for me. I get ActivityNotFoundException. (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=android.resource://com.mypackage.myapp/2130837582 }. LG E400 Android 2.3.6.

Comment: @LucioCrusca - maybe you should specify the intent type - is it jpeg or png image?

Comment: Just a reminder that the constant in the framework is: `ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE`

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me. Before I tried this (which did not work): `Uri uri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(R.id.drawable_name));`

Comment: So is the resource type required or not? It's not working for me when I don't include the resource typ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566840/get-uri-from-drawable-image

Answer (score 94):

Here is a clean solution which fully leverages the [`android.net.Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) class via its [`Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html) pattern, avoiding repeated composition and decomposition of the URI string, without relying on hard-coded strings or ad hoc ideas about URI syntax.

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
    .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
    .authority(resources.getResourcePackageName(resourceId))
    .appendPath(resources.getResourceTypeName(resourceId))
    .appendPath(resources.getResourceEntryName(resourceId))
    .build();
```

Minimally more elegant with Kotlin:

```
fun Context.resourceUri(resourceId: Int): Uri = with(resources) {
    Uri.Builder()
        .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
        .authority(getResourcePackageName(resourceId))
        .appendPath(getResourceTypeName(resourceId))
        .appendPath(getResourceEntryName(resourceId))
        .build()
}
```

In Jetpack Compose:

```
@Composable
fun rememberResourceUri(resourceId: Int): Uri {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    return remember(resourceId) {
        with(context.resources) {
            Uri.Builder()
                .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
                .authority(getResourcePackageName(resourceId))
                .appendPath(getResourceTypeName(resourceId))
                .appendPath(getResourceEntryName(resourceId))
                .build()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this solved my problem. My uri shape was like "android.resource://com.craiovadata.guessthecountry/drawable/sky"

Answer (score 59):

```
public static Uri resourceToUri(Context context, int resID) {
        return Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +
                context.getResources().getResourcePackageName(resID) + '/' +
                context.getResources().getResourceTypeName(resID) + '/' +
                context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(resID) );
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

For those having error, you may be entering the wrong package name. Just use this method.

```
public static Uri resIdToUri(Context context, int resId) {
    return Uri.parse(Consts.ANDROID_RESOURCE + context.getPackageName()
                     + Consts.FORESLASH + resId);
}
```

Where

```
public static final String ANDROID_RESOURCE = "android.resource://";
public static final String FORESLASH = "/";
```

Comment: did you really made a constant for a foreslash??

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer Yes :), although I usually use system constant for foreslash ;)

Answer (score 5):

Based on the answers above I want to share a kotlin example on how to get a valid Uri for any resource in your project. I think it's the best solution because you don't have to type any strings in your code and risk typing it wrongly.

```
    val resourceId = R.raw.scannerbeep // r.mipmap.yourmipmap; R.drawable.yourdrawable
    val uriBeepSound = Uri.Builder()
        .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
        .authority(resources.getResourcePackageName(resourceId))
        .appendPath(resources.getResourceTypeName(resourceId))
        .appendPath(resources.getResourceEntryName(resourceId))
        .build()
```

Comment: This is literally the same thing as Uli's answer ..

Comment: @maxpleaner it literally isn't the same answer, and his answer was edited because it was only in Java, as you know Kotlin for Android is a thing since 2019, original answer 2016. Thank you for your comment. Have a nice day.

Comment: My mistake. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

You want the URI of the image resource, and `R.drawable.goomb` is an image resource. The Builder function creates the URI that you are asking for:

```
String resourceScheme = "res";
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
  .scheme(resourceScheme)
  .path(String.valueOf(intResourceId))
  .build();
```

Comment: So you're passing something like "18" to path. That seems incorrect

Comment: @NickCardoso R.drawable.goomba is the the drawable that I have in my resource folder. If its value is 18, does that make the assignment incorrect ?

Comment: Of course it does. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html#path(java.lang.String) The ID in the R file needs to be used to resolve a real path.

Comment: @NickCardoso thanks but it does not and it works perfectly. The Scheme takes care of that path as the documentation you pointed out suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @xnagyg answer above I've made a convenience extension which hopefully will be useful for others also,

```
fun Resources.getRawUri(@RawRes rawRes: Int) = "%s://%s/%s/%s".format(
    ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE, this.getResourcePackageName(rawRes),
    this.getResourceTypeName(rawRes), this.getResourceEntryName(rawRes)
)
```

which can be used like `context.resources.getRawUri(R.raw.rawid)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getURIForResource (int resourceId) {
        
        return Uri.parse("android.resource://"+BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+"/" +resourceId).toString();
    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?