# How to get the android String PATH to a file on drawable folder?

Tags: android, resources

I'm trying to display locally stored maps with a api to show maps.

I need to know the string path to a map file stored on drawable folder, because i'm using a map api that needs to receive a string path, and my maps must be stored drawable folder (assets folder can't be used for this because the maps are higher than 1MB)

This is the code i'm trying, but this code is incorrect because the map is not being displayed:

```
        MapView mapView = new MapView(this);
        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        String mapName="bremen";           
        String fileName = "android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/drawable/"+mapName;
        //mapView.setMapFile("/sdcard/path/to/mapfile.map");
        mapView.setMapFile(fileName);             
        setContentView(mapView);
```

Wich is the correct string path file to the file bremen.map stored on my drawable folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to know the string path to a map file stored on drawable folder

There is no "string path to a map file stored on drawable folder", because there is no "drawable folder" except on your development machine.

> Wich is the correct string path file to the file bremen.map stored on my drawable folder?

There is none.

Since `MapView` does not have `setMapFile()`, I am assuming you are using some third party implementation. If so, and that implementation is open source, modify it to support a `Uri` in addition to its existing support of a path.

Otherwise, copy the drawable resource to a file first, then supply a path to that file.