# Getting String Based Image Location from Drawable Directory

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am trying to use PDFjet library to print a page to PDF in Android.

The documentation tells me that in order to print an image to PDF, I need to get a handle on the image filename like:

```
String fileName = "images/myimage.png";
```

So now i want to print an image from the `res/drawable` folder. In Android the resources are referenced through R.id which returns an int.

My question is:

How do i get a handle on the image from the drawable folder as string ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the android String PATH to a file on drawable folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476452/how-to-get-the-android-string-path-to-a-file-on-drawable-folder)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
String fileName = "android.resource://your.package.name/" + R.drawable.xxx;;
```

Comment: This is not being recognized as a valid address location. The post at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8476930/2348704 seems to say that this is not even possible to do :(