# Set Notification Sound from Assets folder

Tags: android, notifications, media-player, android-resources, android-assets

I am attaching the sound files in the assets folder for play sound in the notification but I am not able to play sound from the assets folder.

I have setting page from which user can set the sound for the notification and also user can play sound. This part is completed. I am able to play sound from the assets folder using Media Player. I can use same logic at the Notification creation time but problem can be happened when user click on the Notification because media player still playing the sound.

I tried

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/Sound/Long/AlarmClock.mp3");
```

also tried like this

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android_asset/Sound/Long/AlarmClock.mp3");
```

but my issue is still not solved.

Is there any other way to set the sound in the notification from the assets directory ?

**Logcat**

```
01-10 09:57:01.509: ERROR/PlayerDriver(31): Command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE completed with an error or info PVMFErrNotSupported
01-10 09:57:01.509: ERROR/MediaPlayer(52): error (1, -4)
01-10 09:57:01.519: WARN/NotificationService(52): error loading sound for android_asset/Sound/Long/audio.mp3
01-10 09:57:01.519: WARN/NotificationService(52): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
01-10 09:57:01.519: WARN/NotificationService(52):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
01-10 09:57:01.519: WARN/NotificationService(52):     at android.media.AsyncPlayer.startSound(AsyncPlayer.java:64)
01-10 09:57:01.519: WARN/NotificationService(52):     at android.media.AsyncPlayer.access$200(AsyncPlayer.java:33)
01-10 09:57:01.519: WARN/NotificationService(52):     at android.media.AsyncPlayer$Thread.run(AsyncPlayer.java:99)
01-10 09:57:01.519: WARN/PlayerDriver(31): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
```

or any other idea ? Please give me hint.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

put ur mp3 file in `res->raw folder`, try to fetch sound file from `raw folder`.

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.androidbook.samplevideo/" + R.raw.myvideo);
```

**OR**

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.androidbook.samplevideo/raw/myvideo");
```

Comment: Yeah this is great idea to create content provider to access internal files

Comment: Note, i found that the sound had to be an .mp3 to work, not .ogg (like the rest of our sounds).  And, as rajpara showed above, it also seemed necessary to not include the extension.  So my sound file, push.mp3 in the myproject/res/raw folder, worked with: android.resource://com.mycompany.myapp/raw/push

Comment: @rajpara
Please tell me how to code to set this Uri as Ringtone, Notification and Alarm. I didn't find something relevant.

Comment: The first approach of referencing `R.raw.myvideo` will stop working if that resource id ever changes, since the Notification Channel never lets you change the sound/path. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54796493/5301868

Comment: Can't emphasize enough: If you are using this scheme to produce a sound URI to use with a `NotificationChannel`, be aware that the resource ID can change between builds. And, since you can't edit the URI associated with a given `NotificationChannel` (once it has been established), this will cause your app's notification sounds to break randomly after updates. Use [this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340580/6759241) instead; avoid using the integer  resource ID.

Answer (score 8):

This worked perfectly for me. I found it on another post.

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://my.package.name/raw/notification");
```

Comment: Your Uri indicates that you are accessing the resource folder rather than from assets. You are referencing a file from row folder inside your resources.

Comment: Indeed this is good that we put a sound file into the row folder and refer that file.

Answer (score 4):

assets are private resources to that app, I think you wont be able to set them as ringtone, you will need a public file which is accessible by the media process to set ringtone. You will have to copy the file to sdcard to set it as ringtone.

Comment: Yeah I think you are right. to access the private resources I will have to use content provider.

Comment: The question does not concern ringtones.

Answer (score 0):

The correct path to load something from your assets folder is `file:///android_assets/relative_path_to_your_file`. Note the **three slashes** here. Although I have not tried to set a notification sound this way, I have used this with a WebView with success a number of times, and would expect it to work the same way.

Comment: Ok let me try with three slashes

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to access directly the assets audio file to the Notification.
So i follow this steps and so I am able to play audio in the Notification

1. I copy that files to the data directory.
2. Still data directory is not accessible to the Notification sound so I create a custom `Content Provider` to share the audio file in the read more which are now in data folder.
3. Now at the time of notification creation I had set the Uri of the file to the Notification sound.

Now using this steps I am able to set custom sound to the Notification.

Answer (score 0):

ContentProvider is the way to go.
I don't think there is a need to copy files to the data directory like @Dharmendra suggests.
You can access the asset folder directly though the ContentProvider

```
public AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFile(Uri uri, String mode)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    String filePart = Sound.getSoundFileName(uri);

    try {
        return getContext().getResources().getAssets().openFd(filePart + ".ogg");
    }catch(IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "fail " + e.getMessage());

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: and how can i get the Ringtone from this AssetFileDescriptor?

Comment: @wutzebaer You can give NotificationCompat.Builder a URI of a sound to play with the notification.  
  
openAssetFile in your content provider is given this URI and returns the AssetFileDescriptor to the notification to play  
  
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html