# Android Notification custom sound not working

Tags: android, android-notifications

I've searched the web and found some post related to setting sound on android notification and followed them but in my case I am getting default notification sound on android notification. Here's my code:

```
builder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notification_message));
```

I've also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801122/set-notification-sound-from-assets-folder) post, but no luck.

For your information: I've played the URI using MediaPlayer and it's working fine then.

Part of my code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(appContext);
builder.setContentTitle(message.notificationTitle);
builder.setContentText(message.notificationSubtitle);
builder.setTicker(message.notificationTitle);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_inbox);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + appContext.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notification_message);
builder.setSound(uri);
builder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000});
builder.build();
```

Can anyone explain what's the issue. How to do it? I'm stuck :(

Comment: Check your log to see if there's any exception message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry folks. It was my mistake.
I used following line:

```
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
```

which created the problem. commenting the line fixed it.

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Use  **Context.getPackageName()** method to get the package name of Application.

```
 Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notification_message)
```

remove

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notification_message)
```

Comment: do you think I haven't checked the getpackageName() method. It's just working fine.

Comment: My URI is correct. I have played the sound in the URI using Mediaplayer. But it's not working when setting builder.setSound().