# Get URI from drawable image

Tags: android, uri, drawable

How can I get the URI of image saved in drawable. I have tried following formats, but everytime it cannot load the image.

```
imageURI= Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.indoor_thumbnail1);
imageURI=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/drawables/imageName");
 imageURI=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/drawables/imageName.png");
imageURI = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getResources().getResourceTypeName(R.drawable.indoor_thumbnail1)+"/" +getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.indoor_thumbnail1)+".png" );
```

Don't know why I can't fetch the image URI..

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + resources.getResourcePackageName(resId) + '/' + resources.getResourceTypeName(resId) + '/' + resources.getResourceEntryName(resId) );
```

Comment: Works fine on Kit-Kat and Nougat

Answer (score 12):

I found most of the answers confusing for a novice user so i am including an example.

your_package_name = org.xyz.abc

image in drawable is => myimage.jpg

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://org.xyz.abc/drawable/myimage");
or 
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.getPackageName()+"/drawable/myimage");
```

Comment: Simple. Exactly what i needed

Answer (score 10):

This is what you really need:

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
"://" + getResources().getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
+ '/' + getResources().getResourceTypeName(R.drawable.ic_launcher) + '/' + getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.ic_launcher) );
```

Comment: I believe that it should be: 

Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getResources().getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.ic_launcher) + '/' + getResources().getResourceTypeName(R.drawable.ic_launcher) + '/' + String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_launcher );

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.myimage_name);

String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "MyIMG.png");
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    Uri imguri=Uri.fromFile(file);
```