# How to add an image file in android studio and get its uri?

Tags: java, android, image, file, uri

I'm now developing an app using android studio. Now I want to use an image file which is stored at my desktop. Then I also need its uri to do something. Now I put it in drawable file, but I don't know how to call it as a file and get its url.
I think I should implement something like this:

```
File file = new File(?????);
Uri uri = Uri.fromfile(file);
```

What should I put inside the clause? I've tried "res:///"+R.drawable.image, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: what do you need it's URI for?

Comment: I just need it for testing other function, just like comparing the photo capured by phone with the original scanned picture. Now I need to add the original scanned picture...

Comment: to generate URI, you can follow below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566840/get-uri-from-drawable-image/21366723

Comment: @AmbrishKhandal Still doesn't work...

Comment: It said "resolveUri failed"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your image as Bitmap (as far as i understand from your question)
Use this for getting bitmap from drawable folder.

```
Bitmap image= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.image_name);
```

Then you can save this bitmap to the telephone for uri but i think you are trying to access bitmap of it.

Comment: I need to use it as just the File type

Comment: a JPEG file type

Answer (score 0):

To create a file from uri, you also need to provide the file path

Add the following method to your activity outside the onCreate method

```
private String getPath(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getContext(), contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

and then create file like this

```
   String filePath =  getPath(put your uri here);
   File file = new File(filePath);
```

Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

you can get Uri, you will replace pic1 with your image name

Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+this.getPackageName()+"/drawable/pic1");
 img.setImageURI(uri);

Answer (score 0):

try to use ContentResolver to open resource URIs:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/drawable/image_filename");
```

//To open file

```
InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```