# Removing shared preferences also removes default image view

Tags: android

I have an activity where a user can upload a photo. At first, before he chooses a photo there is a default image from the drawable folder. But, since I have shared preferences on that view, in case the user goes back to previous activities, I clean the shared preferences in the `onDestroy` of the main activity, and then when I launch my app again, the image view is blank, instead of displaying the default image.
This is how I save the shared preferences:

ActivityTwo.java;

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("imageUri", imageURI);
    editor.apply();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

On the main activity I clean this preference:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Mypref", 0);
    preferences.edit().remove("imageUri").commit();
}
```

But then when I launch the app again, the image view at the ActivityTwo is just a blank square, without the default image inside.

So, am I doing it right? The way I clear the shared preferences? Why do I have to do it via the `onDestroy` of the main activity and not ActivityTwo?(It didnt work). And how to save the default image view?

This is the xml of the image view:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
android:background="@drawable/image_view_border"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/no_profile_picture" />
```

Comment: Can you show me the code where you load an image?

Comment: post your xml or show how are you setting the default image drawable

Comment: added the xml, thanks

Comment: why are you  storing ImgUri into Shared Preferences?

Comment: what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: The imageUri is actually a string representing the URI, what I wanted to accomplish is that the image that the user just uploaded will be saved in the image view, in case the user goes back to the previous activity to edit his name, and then goes back to the image-editing activity and that the image he previously chose will be saved in that image view

Answer (score 0):

on the activity where you set the default image in the first place, check whether the preference for the custom image is there, if yes, replace the image, if not, use the default.

For example:

```
finalUri = imageUri == null? defaultUri : imageUri;
imageView.setImageURI(finalUri);
```

EDIT: to get the drawable reference you can use the following code:

```
Drawable myImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myImage);
```

Comment: but the default image is in the drawable folder using xml

Comment: you can get the reference to a drawable like so: Drawable myImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myImage);

Comment: But then defaultUri should be of type Drawable, no? then how can it work if you wrote `defaultUri`?

Comment: check how to get Uri from drawable here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566840/get-uri-from-drawable-image

Answer (score 0):

check that the imageuri is null or not, then set image...

```
if(imageURI!=null)
imageView.setImageURI(imageURI)
else imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_profile_picture);
```