# Share image using Intent in Android Recycler View

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-intent, android-recyclerview

This is my data class :-

```
data class User(val imagepic: Int)
```

Passing value to recycler view :-

```
 users.add(User(R.drawable.splash_bc))
        users.add(User(R.drawable.image))
        users.add(User(R.drawable.splash_bc))
        users.add(User(R.drawable.share))
        users.add(User(R.drawable.splash_bc))
        users.add(User(R.drawable.image))
```

this is my share function :-
Here I am passing user as Input

```
  fun shareString(user: User) {
            var image_path: String
            val file : File = File(user)
            val uri = Uri.fromFile(file)
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
            startActivity(itemView.context, Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share to :"),null)
            
        }
```

I am not able to share image. getting casting error everytime.
Please help on this

Comment: Please attach the crash also

Comment: Please use fileprovider for share file. check this link https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider

Comment: Visit this link, it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661875/how-to-use-share-image-using-sharing-intent-to-share-images-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are parsing the drawable file right way.
basically drawable is an int value in "User", You can't parse that to uri.
[check this one for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566840/get-uri-from-drawable-image/27681409)

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me :

```
 fun shareString(context: Context,user: User) {

            val b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, user.mImage)
            val share = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            share.type = "image/jpeg"
            val path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.contentResolver, b, "Title", null)
            val imageUri: Uri = Uri.parse(path)
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri)
            startActivity(context,Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"),null)

        }
```

I have pass context value from mainActivity.