# Loading Drawable Image Resource in Fresco's SimpleDraweeView

Tags: android, fresco

I used **Fresco 0.5.2**:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.5.2'
}
```

I want to use `SimpleDraweeView` to load a gif image from `drawable`.
Here is my code:

```
String path = ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"+ getResources().getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.default_app) + "/"
+ getResources().getResourceTypeName(R.drawable.default_app) + "/"
+ getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.default_app);
Uri uri =  Uri.parse(path);
simpleDraweeView =(SimpleDraweeView)
this.findViewById(R.id.simple_drawee_view);
        ImageRequest imageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uri).build();
        DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                .setImageRequest(imageRequest)
                .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
                .build();
        simpleDraweeView.setController(controller);
```

The `default_app` is just a jpeg image and it doesn't work.

I used this as the [Fresco's documentation mentioned](http://frescolib.org/docs/animations.html#_).
Is there any problem with the path or code?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To get the URI of the resource image to be loaded in Fresco, use "res:/" instead of ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE, which is used for [URIs in a normal case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896223/how-to-get-an-uri-of-an-image-resource-in-android).

```
import com.facebook.common.util.UriUtil;

Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
    .scheme(UriUtil.LOCAL_RESOURCE_SCHEME) // "res"
    .path(String.valueOf(resId))
    .build();
// uri looks like res:/123456789
simpleDraweeView.setImageURI(uri);
```

You should be able to use that URI with a DraweeController too.

Here are Fresco’s [supported URIs](http://frescolib.org/docs/supported-uris.html).

Comment: I'm using Fresco 0.7.0 and 0.8.1, both can't load `res:/` URI. Any idea?

Comment: This kinda works, but be careful you also have to clear the cache for that Uri, in case you have different images for different configurations (like landscape vs portrait)

Comment: Same code is written in following method `UriUtil.getUriForResourceId(resId)` so can use  directly

Answer (score 22):

I'm using Fresco 0.7.0

```
ImageRequest imageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithResourceId(R.drawable.image).build();
SimpleDraweeView draweeView = (SimpleDraweeView) v.findViewById(R.id.picture);
draweeView.setImageURI(imageRequest.getSourceUri());
```

If you are using proguard you need to add these lines in your proguard file:

```
-keep class com.facebook.imagepipeline.gif.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.imagepipeline.webp.** { *; }
```

Comment: Why would the ProGuard lines be necessary?
Why would ProGuard remove them?

Comment: At that time these lines were necessary to get Fresco 0.7.0 working with proguard. See [error here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867642/proguard-error-with-fresco/34351360#34351360). Now for Fresco 0.10.0 maybe it's not necessary anymore. See [proguard config here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/fresco/master/proguard-fresco.pro).

Comment: I don't think so, but maybe developers will add this soon. See [here](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/1008) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/pull/1386)

Answer (score 9):

Try using this:

```
String path = "res:/" + R.drawable.default_app; // Only one slash after res:
simpleDraweeView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path));
```

No need to use ImageRequest or DraweeController.

Answer (score 4):

Try using this:

UriUtil.getUriForResourceId(resId)

Answer (score 4):

You can use

`draweeView.setActualImageResource(R.drawable.background);`

Answer (score 1):

There's an implementation of NoActivity.java's code in the Fresco library:

```
ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithResourceId(R.drawable.resId).build()
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that an XML drawable cannot be directly used as the image in a SimpleDraweeView.

But as the [documentation](https://frescolib.org/docs/supported-uris.html) states, *"If you want to display an XML drawable as the main image, then set it as a placeholder and use the null uri."*

```
draweeView.setImageURI(null as String?)
draweeView.hierarchy.setPlaceholderImage(drawableImage)
```