# Proguard error with fresco

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, android-proguard

I am using ProGuard and when I am running the project in release configuration, I get the following error:

```
Warning:com.facebook.imagepipeline.bitmaps.DalvikBitmapFactory: can't find referenced field 'android.graphics.Bitmap$Config BITMAP_CONFIG' in program class com.facebook.imagepipeline.nativecode.Bitmaps
```

I searched everywhere but couldn't find any clue to solve it. I have updated my `proguard-rules.pro` with what is given in the fresco's docs page.

Fresco dependency:

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.8.1+'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp:0.8.1+'
```

Comment: Are these the rules you added to your ProGuard config? https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/fresco/master/proguard-fresco.pro

Comment: @RobertoArtilesAstelarra yes, exactly.

Comment: Does the app start, or it fails the building process?

Comment: Check out this thread https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/681 Apparently, it's a known issue.

Comment: @RobertoArtilesAstelarra No, the app does not start. Build process fails.

Comment: @RobertoArtilesAstelarra I thought it was an issue with v0.8.0 only. But when I updated to v0.8.1 then also it is there. Is there any workaround? I really need to run ProGuard for Resource Shrinking to work.

Comment: I recommend you to raise this problem in that issue thread on github.

Answer (score 0):

Hi，According from the error

```
 Warning:com.facebook.imagepipeline.bitmaps.DalvikBitmapFactory: can't find referenced field 'android.graphics.Bitmap$Config BITMAP_CONFIG' in program class com.facebook.imagepipeline.nativecode.Bitmaps
```

It show that the warning com.facebook.imagepipeline.bitmaps.** and so on.
my solution is adding the below words to the **proguard-rules.pro** file

```
 -dontwarn com.facebook.imagepipeline.**
```

I have tried this, and it seems be ok ! be sure you open the **build.gradle** file ,

```
android{
   ...
   buildTypes {
      ...
      release{
         ...
         minifyEnabled true
         ...
      }
}
```