# Load Image as a URI in Android.Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I am working on `Xamarin.Android` platform and trying to get the image as follows. However it returns error. I could not able to figure out how to solve it.

```
Uri imageURL = new Uri("Resource.Drawable.Xxxx.png");
```

Comment: My guess is that you don't really need the URI from a resource for whatever is that you're trying to do... What do you want to do with that URI? Opening or displaying an image? Because there are other ways to do so, such as https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/imageview/display_an_image/

Comment: I am using textSharp to generate pdf. and it asks Image. I know how to add a image on Imageview, but there is no imageView on the picture.

Comment: This is not exactly for xamarin, but it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896223/how-to-get-an-uri-of-an-image-resource-in-android