# how to get image path from resource as a string in java in android

Tags: java, android

I want the image path from the `drawable` under resources as a string but it shows error . But I can't identify what the error is. I provide some code snippet.

```
listView = view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

ArrayList<Card> list = new ArrayList<>();

//here the error
String img = "drawable://" + R.drawable.tiger;
```

Note: when I placed image name (tiger) it gives me error

```
list.add(new Card("drawable://" + R.drawable.tiger, "Royal Bengal Tiger"));
```

Comment: why do you use `"drawable://"`? Do you want to access the drawable using name string?

Comment: it is followed by a tutorial.Check this :
https://github.com/mitchtabian/AppBarLayouts/blob/master/ActionBar%20CardView%20Tutorial/ActionBar/app/src/main/java/tabian/com/actionbar/Tab2Fragment.java

Comment: Do you use exactly these classes? I mean `ImageLoader` for example.

Answer (score 1):

> i want the image path from the drawable under resources

A drawable resource is a file on your development machine. It is not a file on the device. There is no path to it on the device.

> i provide some code snippet

There is no `drawable` scheme in Android. This also is not an image path.

If your `Card` requires a `Uri`, you can [try `android.resource` as a scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340580/115145).

Comment: Check this:
https://github.com/mitchtabian/AppBarLayouts/blob/master/ActionBar%20CardView%20Tutorial/ActionBar/app/src/main/java/tabian/com/actionbar/Tab2Fragment.java

Comment: You would need to talk to the developer of that tutorial. We cannot help you with that tutorial, as we did not write it.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you get resources

what you want is `ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.name);`

Comment: Check this:
https://github.com/mitchtabian/AppBarLayouts/blob/master/ActionBar%20CardView%20Tutorial/ActionBar/app/src/main/java/tabian/com/actionbar/Tab2Fragment.java

Comment: That example uses a library called `Universal Image Loader` without going through that library and seeing what is does with that string I cant tell you but its not behavior that you can get without it