# Android generic audio resource object

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a custom `AudioPlayer` class to handle playing audio in my app, and it uses the android [`MediaPlayer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) class under the hood.

It currently has a method `play(source: MediaDataSource)`. This needs to take in some generic source object that it can play, so I decided to use [`MediaDataSource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDataSource.html) which seems right.

How do I obtain a `MediaDataSource` from a resource, e.g. `R.raw.my_audio_file`, so that my custom `AudioPlayer` class can use it? Or is `MediaDataSource` the wrong type to use here, and if so what other type should I use?

Comment: AudioPlayer is not a general android class from my search of the docs. What class are you using ?

Comment: @JoxTraex "I have a custom AudioPlayer class"

Comment: Ah I see, but what is its base class? I ask because that is what will define the standard for how you interact with your media via provided APIs from the super unless you are doing all the low level decoding. One other problem is its unclear who generates MediaDataSources, since the APIs provided on the docs are very simplistic https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDataSource?hl=en . You could use MediaPlayer (https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/MediaPlayer?hl=en#setDataSource(java.io.FileDescriptor)) and translate the resource to URI.

Comment: @JoxTraex I have edited my question. I am using the android `MediaPlayer` under the hood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possiblity is to use:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html?hl=en#setDataSource(java.lang.String)

The string path for local resources/assets could probably be translated to a path/URI via:
[how to get an uri of an image resource in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896223/how-to-get-an-uri-of-an-image-resource-in-android)

And if you have web endpoints this would also work for that as well.

Comment: This nearly works. I now have a `URI` called `uri`. Using `MediaPlayer.create(context, uri)` works, but I don't want to create a new instance every time, so when I use `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(uri.toString())` no audio is played. Maybe I'm using `setDataSource` wrong so I'll keep looking at it

Comment: @DavidCallanan I believe once you create it you only need to call setDataSource again and it'll reuse the same object and decode the new data source. You don't need to call create each time. The difference is when you use create its already setting up the datasource TO that URI. No rule saying you can't have that object load a new datasource.

Comment: Got it to work! I used `.setDataSource(ctx, uri)` instead of `.setDataSource(uri.toString())`. Really appreciate the help! :)

Comment: Nevermind, it's not working. My app is crashing and there is no error message. Probably just a small mistake

Comment: Right, finally got it to work, forgot to call `.prepare()`. Thanks again